# How to track source files loaded in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, file, key, unique

I load files in MySQL. Each file contains:

```
Date ShopNumber subject price quantity total
```

e.g. file1:

```
01/01/2011 Mexico Book1 $10 2 $20
01/01/2011 Mexico Book2 $10 2 $20
01/01/2011 Mexico Book3 $10 2 $20
...............................
```

file2:

```
01/01/2011 Mexico Book4 $10 2 $20
01/01/2011 Mexico Book1 $10 1 $10
...............................
```

In MySQL table:

```
01/01/2011 Mexico Book1 $10 3 $30
01/01/2011 Mexico Book2 $10 2 $20
01/01/2011 Mexico Book3 $10 2 $20
01/01/2011 Mexico Book4 $10 2 $20
...............................
```

The problem is: I have to track the source file and I cannot include source file to unique key of table - I need only keep totals.
Duplicates are rare. May be possible add another table that will keep only duplicates? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what is the question? How to merge the duplicates on import? Or how to log information that a merged value is actually merged from the specific rows on import?

Comment: No, I need to know from which files Book1(..n) was contributed.

Comment: and how do you load them? Using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: I can load in different way, also I you have write. I need elaborate common principles of tracking from which file information was contributed. In any case thank you for interest for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My application includes import functionaly and here is the way I solve the problem of loading data into MySQL and tracking information.

- when the user uploads a file the application re-formats it to the tab-separated uft8-encoded valid temporary file
- the name of the file and some other meta information about the import the application inserts into a separate table `import_info` and retrieves its id (update_id)
- then the application loads the data from the file using `LOAD DATA INFILE` query to which it passes the path to the file and the `update_id` (`attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3` come from file, `update_id` comes from parameter to the query)

  ```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %(file_path)s
  INTO TABLE importdata
  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
  (attr1, att2, att3, update_id)
  SET update_id = %(update_id)s;
  ```
- the `importdata` table in my case allows duplicates which the application merges in other tables after the data is imported. If the merge is successful, I remove the imported data from the `importdata` table.